# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

**Hola hago este codigo para ejemplicar el uso de os.closerange**

```
import os
import sys
    print("Closing a file group with: os.closerange()")
    # abrimos un grupo de paths
    path1 = r"C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Pruebas\prueba1.txt"
    path2 = r"C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Pruebas\prueba2.txt"
    path3 = r"C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Pruebas\prueba3.txt"
    path4 = r"C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Pruebas\prueba4.txt"
    # abrimos lo archivos y obtenemos sus descriptores con os.open()
    fd1 = os.open(path1, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    fd2 = os.open(path2, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    fd3 = os.open(path3, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    fd4 = os.open(path4, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    #
    line = "text file"
    #
    encoded = str.encode(line)
    # Escribimos en todos los archivos
    os.write(fd1, encoded)
    os.write(fd2, encoded)
    os.write(fd3, encoded)
    os.write(fd4, encoded)
    # definimos limites maximo y minimo para el metodo os.closerange()
    fd_min = min(fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4)
    fd_max = max(fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4)
    # cerramos con el metodo
    os.closerange(fd_min, fd_max + 1)
    print("All files are closed successfullly")
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error: **'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**
si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecía mucho

a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
File "C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Prueba\prueba.py", line 176, in switch  os.write(fd1, line)

Comment: si ya tienes bytes no necesitas volver a usar `encode`

Comment: el problema es que si quito esto
`encoded = str.encode(line)`
y pongo directo el line en la esctritura de los files 
    `os.write(fd1, line)`
    `os.write(fd2, line)`
    `os.write(fd3, line)`
    `os.write(fd4, line)`
me da ahora el error contrario de que se requiere bytes y no str
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: podrías colocar el `Traceback`?

Comment: Cómo sería eso??

Comment: Todo el error que te aparece en la consola

Comment: `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
  File "C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Documentos\Prueba\prueba.py", line 176, in switch
    os.write(fd1, line)`

Comment: Listo hermano :)

Comment: Mmm... raro, debería de funcionarte con el encode que tienes. Ese es todo tu código?

Comment: No es `str.encode(line)`, sino `line.encode("utf-8")` (o el encoding que quieras usar). Probablemente en tu código `str` sea alguna variable que contenía bytes (y de ser así, sería un nombre mal elegido para una variable, pues `str` ya es un tipo en Python)

Answer (score 0):

El formato del método `encode` es el siguiente:

```
string_a_codificar.encode(codificación_a_usar)
```

Para lo que deseas debe usar:

```
encoded = line.encode("utf-8")
```

Normalmente el formato es "utf-8" o "ascii" para intercambio,

#### Demo

```
import os

path1 = r"prueba1.txt"
# abrimos lo archivos y obtenemos sus descriptores con os.open()
fd1 = os.open(path1, os.O_RDWR)
line = "text file"
encoded = line.encode("utf-8")
# Escribimos en todos los archivos
os.write(fd1, encoded)
os.close(fd1)
```

produce el archivo

```
jose@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more prueba1.txt 
text file
```